# Problem with understanding function maximization for genetic algorithm

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

I am trying to implement a fitness function for a genetic algorithm and have problem with understanding what function maximization means.
In the paper which I use as the basis of the algorithm, the fitness function is defined as **(1-RC) + (1-RO)**, where RC and RO are floating point values between 0 and 1, which I calculate using another formulas. 
However in the next paragraph of the article it is written - **"This function (fitness function) has to be maximized"**

I am struggling to understand what that means. Could you please explain it in easy-to-understand way for a Math noob? Thank you!

Comment: We need a lot more information about the problem. "Maximization" means find value(s) of the input variable(s) that make the function as large as possible. In this case that would mean making RC and RO as small as possible. If that doesn't make sense in your problem then you haven't yet asked a question we can answer.

Comment: Alright, thank you, I think I get it now. This is the whole purpose of the fitness function in evolutionary programming, to evolve the most suitable individual with parameters which will cause the fitness function to reach maximum value.
I thought there is something more to this, math-related which I don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, there's no more math than that (though there may be lots of math in calculating the inputs - if they're not related you just make each as small as possible independent of the other). You can post your understanding as an answer to your own question, or delete it. No point leaving it hanging around waiting for an answer.

Comment: Okay, have done that. Thanks!

Comment: Now accept your own answer (the check mark) and everyone will know it's done.

Comment: It says that I can accept my answer tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Alright, thank you, I think I get it now. This is the whole purpose of the fitness function in evolutionary programming, to evolve the most suitable individual with parameters which will cause the fitness function to reach maximum value. I thought there is something more to this, math-related which I don't understand. Thanks!